# Why am I having this error message from g++?

Tags: c++, g++, iostream

Below is my code. It compiles fine in g++, but there is always this running time error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Where am I wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void sort_string(string x){
    for (int i=0;x.size();i++){
                    for(int j=i;x.size();j++){
                            char temp = x[i];
                            if (temp > x[j]){
                                    x[j]=temp;
                                    x[i]=x[j];
                            }
                    }
    }
}


int main(){
    string words;
    cin >> words;

    while (words != " "){
            cout << words << " ";
            sort_string(words);
            cout << words << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try compiling your source with gcc instead of g++ !

Comment: Compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and then use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: i was stupid... I couldnt believe i asked this type of question. But thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping beyond the bounds of the string. You need this:

```
for (int i=0; i<x.size(); i++){ ... }
```

Similarly for the inner loop. `x.size()` will evaluate to `true` unless the string is empty. Since this is the loop termination condition, the loops will run forever for non-empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition makes no sense. That `x.size()` part in your for loops should be a condition to terminate your loops. This will always return some non-zero value unless your string is 0 which means that your code executes infinitely. Then, j always increments and you go out of bounds. You need to supply a valid condition such as `i < x.size()` and `j < x.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions of your for are wrong.
Replace

```
for (int i=0;x.size();i++){
    for(int j=i;x.size();j++){
```

with

```
for (int i=0; i<x.size();i++){
    for(int j=i; j<x.size();j++){
```

otherwhise you will loop endlessy