# Why does not this file compile in gcc? It works fine in VS

Tags: c++, linux, g++

g++ would nt even compile it. Where was I wrong? These are the error message:

gcc sign.c
sign.c: In function âmainâ:
sign.c:35:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-           security]

==================================================================================

```
#include "stdio.h"

int string_length(char str[]);
void string_sort(char s[]);

void string_sort(char s[])
{
    char tmpt;
    int i, j, len;
    len=string_length(s);
    for(i=0; i<len-1; i++){
            for (j=i+1; j<len; j++){
                    if (s[i] > s[j]){
                            tmpt=s[i];
                            s[i]=s[j];
                            s[j]=tmpt;
                    }
            }
    }
}


int string_length(char str[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<80; i++){
            if(str[i]=='\0'){
                    return(i);
            }
    }
}

int main(){
    char words[80];
scanf("%s", words);
    printf(words);
    string_sort(words);
    printf(" ");
    printf(words);
    printf("\n");




    while ( words != " "){
            scanf("%s", words);
            printf(words);
            string_sort(words);
            printf(" ");
            printf(words);
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very strongly not C++ code

Comment: @sehe: That's not really a constructive comment, because that code *can* be compiled with a C++ compiler. Just because it's not how you would write it, doesn't mean it's not C++ code.

Comment: @GregHewgill have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/q/12887060/85371. I wonder where the OP gets the code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, that's just a *warning* message, which means the compiler detected something probably wrong but compiled your code anyway. Not all compilers give the same warnings, as you've noticed.

The problem is this line (and all the other lines like it):

```
printf(words);
```

When using `printf`, you *must* use a format string, something like this:

```
printf("%s", words);
```

Otherwise, if the things you're printing (`words`) happens to have any `%` characters in it, then `printf()` will treat those as formatting specifiers and try to read arguments that you haven't supplied.

If you just want to print a string by itself, then `puts` can be useful:

```
puts(words);
```

This prints `words` followed by a newline.

Comment: That's possible, but the OP doesn't state either way.

Answer (score 3):

The warning says basically that you have to write

```
printf("%s", words);
```

instead of just

```
printf(words);
```

Indeed, using it could be a potential bug in your program, and even a security breach, e.g. if `words` is controlled by the user (which is exactly the case for your program) and may therefore contain `%n` etc. In your case, `words` will be treated as a format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use printf with an unknown format string:

```
printf(words);
```

Try

```
printf("%s", words);
```

In this case,

```
printf("%s\n", words);
puts(words); // includes \n
```

would be nice